# when data come MSSQL server through SOAP api in JSON formate how to create push notification

Tags: android, json, database, push-notification

My Data in MSSQL Server.Create Soap API Webservice in Visual Studio and Give MSSQL Server Database Data in JSON formate. this JSON data used in android app.

So,How to Create Push Notification when New Data Record insert or in MSSQL server then Give Notification android App User?

Comment: Keep the last known data in sqlite, use a job scheduler to poll the JSON data, if it is different then push the notification.

Comment: Please, Give Me Description in Details.

Answer (score 0):

These are the things you need to look at: 
1. [Job scheduler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html)

2. [Async task to get the data](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

3. [SQLite](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html)

Get your hands dirty, learn and implement some of it, post the code that you tried, then I can definitely help you out.

For the start you need to follow below steps:

1. For the first time get the JSON and put it a SQLite database.
2. Next time onwards, keep polling the service to get the JSON and check if it is same as what you have inserted in the SQLite (Of course, by comparing you can do that)
3. If it is different push a notification to the user, else, keep polling using your Job Scheduler.

Comment: MSSQL server database Updated Record  how to give push notification in android app user via soap Api Webservice.